# How to change public string value in android Fragment with onResponse json function

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to get page text from my SQL database and show it in TextView in Android Fragment.

I got the data, but when i am trying to parse it to public string, the result is NULL.

i created public String pageText and uset setText(pageText), and tryed to parse json text to pageText but the result is empty and not showing the page text in TextView

here is my code:

```
 package per.mikha.programs.medjobs.ui.home;

import android.app.VoiceInteractor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import per.mikha.programs.medjobs.R;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    public String pageText;
    public final String GET_BY_ID = "https://xxxxxx.com/mekha.php?id=";


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);

        getData("1");
        textView.setText(pageText);
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),pageText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });*/
        return root;

    }

    public void getData(String id){
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, GET_BY_ID+id, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
       

     try {
                String title = response.getString("title");
                String theText = response.getString("text");
                pageText=theText;
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),theText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQuere = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQuere.add(request);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets pick this apart:

```
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);

    getData("1");
    textView.setText(pageText);
```

and you say that pageText is `null` when `setText` is called.  So lets look at what `getData` does:

```
public void getData(String id){
    JsonObjectRequest request = 
            new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, GET_BY_ID+id, null, 
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                         try {
                             String title = response.getString("title");
                             String theText = response.getString("text");
                             pageText = theText;
                         } catch (JSONException e) {
                             // ...
                         }
                    }
               }, 
               new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    // ...
               }
    );
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

So ... `getData` prepares a request with a response listener and an error handler, adds it to the request queue **and then immediately returns**.

Some time later, the request is sent and the response is received.  Then the `onResponse` method is called, the JSON is parsed and `pageText` is set to a (presumably) non-null value.

But here's the problem.  As soon as the `getData` call returns, the caller do this:

```
    textView.setText(pageText);
```

The chances are that the response to the request won't have arrived yet, and `pageText` won't have been set yet.  Ooops.

But I don't think you will be able *wait* for the response before returning from `getData`.  That would block the UI thread.  So what *I think* you need to do is to put the code that calls `textView.setText` into the response listener's `onResponse` method.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the pagetext variable and set the textview on response

Answer (score 0):

For your intention, 'getData' method must works synchronously. But your code isn't.
To make sure to work correctly, Modify 'getData' method to work synchronized or Call 'setText' method after 'onResponse' method.